# Updating css within div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to update the css within a div using its id via :

```
$(this.id).removeClass("myCss");
```

Should'nt this work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your selector is wrong:

```
$(this).removeClass("myCss");
```

Or, if you want to use the `id`, you'd need to concatenate it in:

```
$( "#" + this.id ).removeClass("myCss");
```

But that's really not necessary if `this` references your element to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

To select object by ID you should use `#` prefix:

```
$("#" + this.id).removeClass("myCss");
```

Otherwise, use just:

```
$(this).removeClass("myCss");
```

Comment: While what you say is certainly true, in this instance it'd be much easier to use `$(this)` (as in [Jonathan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10655174/82548)).

Comment: @DavidThomas True, but OP is trying to *update the css within a div using its id*. So correct solution of selection by ID should be provided first IMHO. Who knows what is the reason for the question.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't intending to criticise the answer, and it is, as noted, absolutely correct. It's just that since the  OP's using `this.id`, he already has access to `this`, which seems to make selecting the current element by its `id` somewhat redundant. I guess I was just trying to provide an easier alternative, but perhaps in a very poorly-communicated way. =/

Comment: @DavidThomas I absolutely accept your logic and share it. However my idea was to show how to fix the mistake first, and then provide the alternative solution. Once I also posted the better alternative to the answer and got couple of downvotes for not following the real question, meanwhile the number of upvotes (from intelligent people) was higher.

Answer (score 3):

No, it shouldn't :-)  Just do

```
$(this).removeClass('myCss');
```

When selecting elements by "id" value, you have to include a leading "#" before the string. There's no point to doing that, however, if you've already got a reference to the DOM node.

Answer (score 1):

you should do:

```
$(this).removeClass("myCss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right code:

```
$(this).removeClass('myCss')
```